# getElementById("...").className is null when trying to use string+variable as id

Tags: javascript

I managed to have code to change class for button with function when conditions met. Problem is I don't want to repeat this for all the elements, but it doesn't work when using `document.getElementById('buy'+gen)` instead of `document.getElementById('buyhotdog')`. I will provide below the "working code" and the code I tried to get working.

Working code:

```
function changeButtonHD() {
    if (money < hotdog.cost) {
        document.getElementById('buyhotdog').className = 'buttongrey';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('buyhotdog').className = 'button';
    }
}
```

and it works with: `changeButtonHD();` in interval that activates with window.onload.

Non-working code:

```
function changeButtonBC(gen) {
    if (money < gen.cost) {
        document.getElementById('buy'+gen).className = 'buttongrey';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('buy'+gen).className = 'button';
    }
}
```

And I tried to get it to work with `changeButtonHD(hotdog);`

Comment: You are missing the quotes  `changeButtonHD('hotdog');`. Using only `hotdog`  on the one hand should throw an error that `hotdog`  is not defined, or if it is defined then the content for the variable named `hotdog` is most likely not the value `hotdog`.

Comment: Are you sure `gen` is the right thing to use, since you're both checking against `gen.cost` then appending _just_ `gen` to `"buy"`?

Comment: Simple debugging: `console.log('buy'+gen)` – what does that give you...?

Comment: deceze> it returns "gen is not defined", guess im doing something badly wrong with this one..

James Thorpe> I guess I'm thinking something wrong here..

t.niese> thanks, that removes so it's not "null" anymore, but it doesn't change the class.

Comment: @veix How are you sending `gen`? What are you sending to the function? I would recommend using a variable to point to the sent parameter and use it instead of using what is being sent. Please post the HTML where you are calling the `changeButtonBX(gen)` function.

Comment: @SiKni8 gen was just a placeholder, I want to make the changeButtonBC() to be such that it can be applied to multiple objects, since I have many buttons. (I'm having self-project for incremental game, beginner level)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here: `gen.cost` you show that `gen` is an object with a property called `cost`.

Here: `'buy'+gen` you use `get` as if it was a string. Unless you've overridden `.toString()` then it will be `"[object Object]"` which is not `"hotdog"`.

You seem to be trying to use the name of the variable that originally held the value you passed to `changeButtonHD`, but you can't (because you passed its value and not its name).

Make `"hotdog"` the value of a property on that object, then use `'buy' + gen.name`.

Comment: gen was just a placeholder, I noticed that I have approached the problem at wrong direction. I'd want to make the function changeButtonBC to be applicable to multiple objects, any tip how to achieve that?

Comment: @veix — Exactly as I said in the answer.

Comment: Ah, now I got it and it works! Thank you so much! It was simple solution, but I guess sometimes you need someone else to point it out!

Answer (score 1):

gen type is object, so if you wanna to get gen value, your gen variable format should like this

```
gen = {cost =1000, value=hotdog} //here an example of your data

function changeButtonBC(gen) {
if (money < gen.cost) {
    document.getElementById('buy'+gen.value).className = 'buttongrey';
}
else {
    document.getElementById('buy'+gen.value).className = 'button';
}
```

}

Comment: This is kind of what I want to do, but how to make it so I don't need to give object name before calling function? I want to use it for multiple objects.